# Load css in Meteor with Fourseven:scss

Tags: meteor, sass

I'm using fourseven:scss to compile scss files. This seems to work fine if I include my `.scss` files under the client directory. However I'd like to leave them near my components either in `/imports/ui/stylesheets/` or else right next to the components in `/imports/ui/components/`. It's just that nothing seems to happen when I leave them there.

The fourseven [documentation](https://atmospherejs.com/fourseven/scss) says that the packages searches all directories and complies `.css` files from any `.scss` files it finds. These are then packaged up and sent down to the browser. I can see a resource "merged-stylesheets-prefixed.css" when I put my `.scss` in the client directory. I just can't see anything when I put it under imports.

How do I control this behaviour?

Answer (score 6):

Try creating a `main.scss` file in the `client` folder and from there import all your other files, like e.g.:

```
@import "{}/imports/ui/components/_ComponentABC.scss";
```

Does it work?

Comment: Yes, that works. Not what I was expecting (although thinking about it that's how I've worked with sass on other projects). Thanks.

Comment: Great! Please, consider accepting my answer then. Cheers.

Comment: I'm still holding out for a solution I prefer - I did +1 your answer :)

Comment: What would you prefer?

Comment: I'm not sure - maybe having nothing in /client and everything in /imports. Perhaps it's having things work as the documentation seemed to suggest and pulling everything without having to write @import statements. I don't think I'd know until I see it.

Comment: From what I understand, having everything in `/imports` and not importing it, is not possible. That's what this folder is for. Put it anywhere else and it will be imported automagically.