# where to put main scss file in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, sass, materialize

Where exactly do you put main.scss files in meteor. I followed this https://github.com/poetic/meteor-materialize-scss
to install *fourseven:scss* and *poetic:materialize-scss* and I can see that the materialize icons are loaded properly. However I am unable to see the css loaded.

I created a main.scss and typed in the following line:

```
/client/main.scss

@import "{poetic:materialize-scss}/sass/materialize.scss";
```

Is this the right place to put main.scss? How does meteor load scss files?

My config: 
Windows 10 
Meteor 1.5.5.5 
fourseven:scss@4.5.4 
poetic:materialize-scss@1.2.10

Edit: Added packages used.

Packages used:

```
accounts-base                     1.3.4  A user account system
accounts-password                 1.4.1  Password support for accounts
aldeed:autoform                   5.8.1* Easily create forms with automatic 
insert and update, and automatic reactive...
aldeed:autoform-select2           2.0.3* Custom select2 input type for AutoForm
aldeed:collection2-core           2.0.1  Core package for aldeed:collection2
aldeed:delete-button              2.0.0  Provides a delete button UI component
aldeed:simple-schema              1.5.3  A simple schema validation object with reactivity. Used by collection2 and a...
blaze-html-templates              1.1.2  Compile HTML templates into reactive UI with Meteor Blaze 
check                             1.2.5  Check whether a value matches a pattern
dynamic-import                    0.1.3  Runtime support for Meteor 1.5 dynamic import(...) syntax
ecmascript                        0.8.3  Compiler plugin that supports ES2015+ in all .js files
ecwyne:mathjs                     2.7.0  Mathjs, An extensive math library for JavaScript, packaged for Meteor. See h...
email                             1.2.3  Send email messages
es5-shim                          4.6.15  Shims and polyfills to improve ECMAScript 5 support
gildaspk:autoform-materialize     0.0.26  Materialize theme for Autoform
johanbrook:publication-collector  1.0.10  Test a Meteor publication by collecting its output.
jquery                            1.11.10  Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors
kadira:blaze-layout               2.3.0  Layout Manager for Blaze (works well with FlowRouter)
kadira:flow-router                2.12.1  Carefully Designed Client Side Router for Meteor
less                              2.7.9  Leaner CSS language
meteor-base                       1.1.0  Packages that every Meteor app needs
meteorhacks:aggregate             1.3.0  Proper MongoDB aggregations support for Meteor
mobile-experience                 1.0.5  Packages for a great mobile user experience
momentjs:moment                   2.19.1  Moment.js (official): parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates - offi...
mongo                             1.2.2  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP
natestrauser:select2              4.0.3  Select2 is a jQuery based replacement for select boxes.
npm-bcrypt                        0.9.3  Wrapper around the bcrypt npm package
practicalmeteor:mocha             2.4.5_6  Write package tests with mocha and run them in the browser or from the com...
reactive-var                      1.0.11  Reactive variable
session                           1.1.7  Session variable
standard-minifier-css             1.3.5  Standard css minifier used with Meteor apps by default.
standard-minifier-js              2.1.2  Standard javascript minifiers used with Meteor apps by default.
tracker                           1.1.3  Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks
underscore                        1.0.10  Collection of small helpers: _.map, _.each, ...
useraccounts:flow-routing         1.14.2  UserAccounts package providing routes configuration capability via kadira:f...
New versions of these packages are available! Run 'meteor update' to try to update those packages to their latest
```

versions. If your packages cannot be updated further, try typing `meteor add <package>@<newVersion>` to see more
  information.

Comment: Have you read this? https://github.com/poetic/meteor-materialize-scss/issues/23#issuecomment-326268810

Comment: I did that, still nothing came through. Eventually I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869837/load-css-in-meteor-with-foursevenscss, but didn't work either.

Comment: Show your meteor packages, please

Comment: Edited to show packages. I have removed fourseven:scss, poetic:materialize-scss currently, these are the only 2 packages missing, but somehow my routes.js isn't loading properly and console is throwing error that "/" path cannot be found. I have given up, and now setting up a new project to import everything cleanly from this old project...